# How does angular2 distinguishes between Light DOM or Shadow DOM inside components view

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm reading [this article](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/08/20/host-and-visibility-in-angular-2-dependency-injection.html) on host and visibility and it states the following about `viewProviders` metadata property of `Component` decorator:

> With viewProviders we can tell the DI system very specifically, which
>   providers are available to which child injectors (Light DOM or Shadow
>   DOM).

I'm wondering how angular2 distinguishes between Light DOM or Shadow DOM inside components template?

This article also mentiones `<ng-content>` tag:

> If we configure Angular accordingly, this DOM tree can be Shadow DOM.
>   That’s also why we have an  tag there. It’s Angular’s
>   implementation of content insertion points, which is another Shadow
>   DOM feature.

So anythying that is put inside `ng-content` is considered `Shadow DOM`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a components template like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-comp',
  template: `
    <div>shadow DOM<div>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
    <div>shadow DOM<div>`, 
    ...
```

and use it like

```
<my-comp>
  <div>light DOM</div>
</my-comp>
```

then it will result in

```
<my-comp>
  <div>shadow DOM</div>
  <div>light DOM</div>
  <div>shadow DOM<div>
</my-comp>
```

Therefore, the light DOM is not really the content of a components template, it is just child content projected at a predefined location within the shadow DOM.

If the default view encapsulation `Emulate` is used, shadow DOM will only be emulated. Only with `Native` it will become a real shadow DOM on browsers that support it.

Comment: thanks, _If the default view encapsulation Emulate is used, shadow DOM will only be emulated._ - but the injector will work similiary in with `Emulate ` and `Native`, correct?

Comment: Yes, the emulated behavior is matched here. Only browser features that are hard to emulate are not emulated (styles are added to `<head>` instead of the components element, CSS encapsulation is limited, ...)

Comment: got it, thanks, it seems that the idea for `<ng-content></ng-content>` is similiart ot `<translcude` in angular1, right?

Comment: Exactly. It's more aligned with the `<content></content>` element the browsers with shadow DOM support support natively